# IR camera not working in Ubuntu with Howdy "No suitable IR camera found, aborting install"

Tags: 20.04

It works fine with Windows login, but when I'm setting up camera with Howdy in Ubuntu 20.04, it tries a few variations, and gives "No suitable IR camera found, aborting install.". Red light never comes up like it does in Windows.

Comment: Edit your question and include the output of `ls -l /dev/video*`. Also, is your camera in this list: https://github.com/boltgolt/howdy/wiki/Cameras-that-have-been-verified-to-work-with-Howdy. (If it isn't don't worry, the list is not complete; if it is, you have assurance that someone else already got it to work).

Answer (score 0):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
device="/dev/whatever"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, but there is one more step.

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.